# I want the number of acounts that have opportunity closing dates within 3 different date ranges

Tags: soql, query

I am trying to get the number of results, or just the results, of unique individuals that are in the result set of the first query, AND EITHER the second OR third.

First Query:

```
SELECT  AccountId 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE StageName = 'Posted' 
AND RecordTypeID = '012800000002KPtAAM'  
AND  CloseDate >= 2015-09-01 
AND CloseDate <= 2015-12-31 
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT  AccountId 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE StageName = 'Posted' 
AND RecordTypeID = '012800000002KPtAAM'  
AND  CloseDate >= 2014-09-01 
AND CloseDate <= 2015-8-31 
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Third Query:

```
SELECT  AccountId 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE StageName = 'Posted' 
AND RecordTypeID = '012800000002KPtAAM'  
AND  CloseDate >= 2013-09-01 
AND CloseDate <= 2014-8-31 
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Comment: That is much more readable, and I see that's how those statements should be posted. Thank you Sebastian.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, either or is the exact keyword you need to use to combine these three queries. So i put up the query common for these three queries

```
SELECT  AccountId 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE StageName = 'Posted' 
AND RecordTypeID = '012800000002KPtAAM'  
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Then we have the conditions for date ranges in three queries

```
AND  CloseDate >= 2015-09-01 
AND CloseDate <= 2015-12-31 

AND  CloseDate >= 2014-09-01 
AND CloseDate <= 2015-8-31 

AND  CloseDate >= 2013-09-01 
AND CloseDate <= 2014-8-31
```

To combine all these with either or condition it should be

```
CloseDate >= 2015-09-01 AND CloseDate <= 2015-12-31 
OR
CloseDate >= 2014-09-01 AND CloseDate <= 2015-8-31 
OR
CloseDate >= 2013-09-01 AND CloseDate <= 2014-8-31
```

But using like above have some confusions. So add some rounded brackets around them.

```
(CloseDate >= 2015-09-01 AND CloseDate <= 2015-12-31) 
OR
(CloseDate >= 2014-09-01 AND CloseDate <= 2015-8-31)
OR
(CloseDate >= 2013-09-01 AND CloseDate <= 2014-8-31)
```

We need to join this with the original common query with an AND condition. So we use another round bracket to keep that AND common to this whole condition.

```
SELECT  AccountId 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE StageName = 'Posted' 
AND RecordTypeID = '012800000002KPtAAM' 
AND ((CloseDate >= 2015-09-01 AND CloseDate <= 2015-12-31) 
    OR
    (CloseDate >= 2014-09-01 AND CloseDate <= 2015-8-31)
    OR
    (CloseDate >= 2013-09-01 AND CloseDate <= 2014-8-31))
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer misses the point that he's looking for `COND1 AND (COND2 OR COND3)`, plus the fact that they are all mutually exclusive

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at your 3 queries, they have **mutually exclusive date ranges**:

```
AND CloseDate >= 2015-09-01 
AND CloseDate <= 2015-12-31 

AND CloseDate >= 2014-09-01 
AND CloseDate <= 2015-8-31 

AND CloseDate >= 2013-09-01 
AND CloseDate <= 2014-8-31
```

They are 3 mutually exclusive date ranges. As such, you will not find a record that matches both the first condition AND either of the other two.

I think that what you're really looking for is something else. Could you explain in business terms what you want to achieve with those queries? Perhaps they are incorrect to begin with.